# Returning tuple of unknown length from python UDF and then applying hash in Pig

Tags: python, hash, apache-pig, udf

This is a question that has two parts:

First, I have a python UDF that creates a list of strings of unknown length.  The input to the UDF is a `map` (`dict` in python) and the number of keys is essentially unknown (it is what I'm trying to obtain).

What I don't know is how to output that in a schema that lets me return it as a list (or some other iterable data structure). This is what I have so far:

```
@outputSchema("?????") #WHAT SHOULD THE SCHEMA BE!?!?
def test_func(input):

    output = []
    for k, v in input.items():

        output.append(str(key))

    return output
```

Now, the second part of the question. Once in Pig I want to apply a [SHA](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/hashing.html) hash to each element in the "list" for all my users. Some Pig pseudo code:

```
USERS = LOAD 'something' as (my_map:map[chararray])
UDF_OUT = FOREACH USERS GENERATE my_udfs.test_func(segment_map)
SHA_OUT = FOREACH UDF_OUT GENERATE SHA(UDF_OUT)
```

The last line is likely wrong as I want to apply the SHA to each element in the list, NOT to the whole list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, since you are returning a python list who's contents are a string, you will want your decorator to be

```
@outputSchema('name_of_bag:{(keys:chararray)}')
```

It can be confusing when specifying this structure because you only need to define what *one* element in the bag would look like.

That being said, there is a much simpler way to do what you require.  There is a function `KEYSET()` ([You can reference this question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628560/how-to-extract-keys-from-map/24770703#24770703)) that will extract the keys from a Pig Map.  So using the data set from that example and adding a few more keys to the first one since you said your map contents are variable in length

```
maps
----
[a#1,b#2,c#3,d#4,e#5]
[green#sam,eggs#I,ham#am]
```

**Query**:

```
REGISTER /path/to/jar/datafu-1.2.0.jar;
DEFINE datafu.pig.hash.SHA();

A = LOAD 'data' AS (M:[]);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(KEYSET(M));
hashed = FOREACH B GENERATE $0, SHA($0);
DUMP hashed;
```

**Output**:

```
(d,18ac3e7343f016890c510e93f935261169d9e3f565436429830faf0934f4f8e4)
(e,3f79bb7b435b05321651daefd374cdc681dc06faa65e374e38337b88ca046dea)
(b,3e23e8160039594a33894f6564e1b1348bbd7a0088d42c4acb73eeaed59c009d)
(c,2e7d2c03a9507ae265ecf5b5356885a53393a2029d241394997265a1a25aefc6)
(a,ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb)
(ham,eccfe263668d171bd19b7d491c3ef5c43559e6d3acf697ef37596181c6fdf4c)
(eggs,46da674b5b0987431bdb496e4982fadcd400abac99e7a977b43f216a98127721)
(green,ba4788b226aa8dc2e6dc74248bb9f618cfa8c959e0c26c147be48f6839a0b088)
```